# If product has attirbute then echo

Tags: php, magento

I have added a delivery time attribute called leadtime to some products in magento. I have displayed the attribute with the following:

```
 <div id="lead-time"><?php echo "Lead time " . $_product->getleadtime();  ?></div>
```

However the prefix text of Lead time is displaying on every product as I have not successfully written a condition to check if the product has the attribute of leadtime. Every method I have tried so far has either displayed on all pages still or given a null error.

How can I write a conditional statement so the div#lead-time only displays on the product that is using the attribute leadtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="lead-time"><?php echo $_product->getleadtime() == "" ? "" : "Lead time " . $_product->getleadtime();  ?></div>
```

Code with optional rendering div:

```
<?php $lead_time = $_product->getleadtime();
if($lead_time != ""){ ?>
<div id="lead-time"><?php echo "Lead time " . $lead_time ;  ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: If you get error on `$_product->getleadtime()` this is problem of your realisation of this method.

Comment: Would you explain why you have to close the php tag after the curly brace bracket and then open one before the curly brace bracket?

Comment: also, I get the if $lead_time isnt eqaul to display nothing. But there is not an else statement.... so why does it work?

Comment: @ADRIAN of course. When I close php tag after if's curly bracket, then interpretaror don't proceed html markup directly and it improve perfomance. I open php tag in place where I need to close php statement or make some another operations with php code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138036/discussion-between-adrian-and-pavlo-zhukov).